# authentication middleware express typescript Error

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, mongoose

I am using express, typescript and mongoose as backend programming.

Below is the following error. I am getting this while making author-blogs API management system. I am not getting users'id while authenticating the users. Why is that so? What mistake I am doing. How do I store the user's id in another way for authentication?

**Error:**

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
    at PostsController.createPost
```

**user.interface.ts**

```
interface User {
  _id: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

export default User;
```

**auth.middle.ts**

```
import { NextFunction, Response,Request } from 'express';
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import AuthenticationTokenMissingException from '../exceptions/AuthenticationTokenMissingException';
import WrongAuthenticationTokenException from '../exceptions/WrongAuthenticationTokenException';
import DataStoredInToken from '../interfaces/dataStoredInToken';
import RequestWithUser from '../interfaces/requestWithUser.interface';
import userModel from '../users/user.model';
import User from 'users/user.interface';

async function authMiddleware(request: RequestWithUser,req:Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  const cookies = req.cookies;
  if (cookies && cookies.Authorization) {
    const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET;
    try {
      const verificationResponse = jwt.verify(cookies.Authorization, secret) as DataStoredInToken;
      const id = verificationResponse._id;
      const user = await userModel.findById(id);
      if (user) {
        request.user = user;
//something wrong is here,I guess ????? 
        next();
      } else {
        next(new WrongAuthenticationTokenException());
      }
    } catch (error) {
      next(new WrongAuthenticationTokenException());
    }
  } else {
    next(new AuthenticationTokenMissingException());
  }
}
export default authMiddleware;
```

**authentication.controller.ts**

```
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import * as express from 'express';
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import User from 'users/user.interface';
import UserWithThatEmailAlreadyExistsException from '../exceptions/UserWithThatEmailAlreadyExistsException';
import WrongCredentialsException from '../exceptions/WrongCredentialsException';
import Controller from '../interfaces/controller.interface';
import DataStoredInToken from '../interfaces/dataStoredInToken';
import TokenData from '../interfaces/tokenData.interface';
import validationMiddleware from '../middleware/validation.middleware';
import CreateUserDto from '../users/user.dto';
import userModel from './../users/user.model';
import LogInDto from './logIn.dto';

class AuthenticationController implements Controller {
  public path = '/auth';
  public router = express.Router();
  private user = userModel;

  constructor() {
    this.initializeRoutes();
  }

  private initializeRoutes() {
    this.router.post(`${this.path}/register`, validationMiddleware(CreateUserDto), this.registration);
    this.router.post(`${this.path}/login`, validationMiddleware(LogInDto), this.loggingIn);
    this.router.post(`${this.path}/logout`, this.loggingOut);
  }

  private registration = async (request: express.Request, response: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) => {
    const userData: CreateUserDto = request.body;
    if (
      await this.user.findOne({ email: userData.email })
    ) {
      next(new UserWithThatEmailAlreadyExistsException(userData.email));
    } else {
      const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(userData.password, 10);
      const user = await this.user.create({
        ...userData,
        password: hashedPassword,
      });
      user.password = undefined;
      const tokenData = this.createToken(user);
      response.setHeader('Set-Cookie', [this.createCookie(tokenData)]);
      response.send(user);
    }
  }

  private loggingIn = async (request: express.Request, response: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) => {
    const logInData: LogInDto = request.body;
    const user = await this.user.findOne({ email: logInData.email });
    if (user) {
      const isPasswordMatching = await bcrypt.compare(logInData.password, user.password);
      if (isPasswordMatching) {
        user.password = undefined;
        const tokenData = this.createToken(user);
        response.setHeader('Set-Cookie', [this.createCookie(tokenData)]);
        response.send(user);
      } else {
        next(new WrongCredentialsException());
      }
    } else {
      next(new WrongCredentialsException());
    }
  }

  private loggingOut = (request: express.Request, response: express.Response) => {
    response.setHeader('Set-Cookie', ['Authorization=;Max-age=0']);
    response.sendStatus(200);
  }

  private createCookie(tokenData: TokenData) {
    return `Authorization=${tokenData.token}; HttpOnly; Max-Age=${tokenData.expiresIn}`;
  }

  private createToken(user: User): TokenData {
    const expiresIn = 60 * 60; // an hour
    const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET;
    const dataStoredInToken: DataStoredInToken = {
      _id: user._id,
    };
    return {
      expiresIn,
      token: jwt.sign(dataStoredInToken, secret, { expiresIn }),
    };
  }

}

export default AuthenticationController;
~~~

**posts.controller.ts**
~~~
import * as express from 'express';
import PostNotFoundException from '../exceptions/PostNotFoundException';
import Controller from '../interfaces/controller.interface';
import RequestWithUser from '../interfaces/requestWithUser.interface';
import authMiddleware from '../middleware/auth.middleware';
import validationMiddleware from '../middleware/validation.middleware';
import CreatePostDto from './post.dto';
import Post from './post.interface';
import postModel from './posts.model';

class PostsController implements Controller {
  public path = '/posts';
  public router = express.Router();
  private post = postModel;

  constructor() {
    this.initializeRoutes();
  }

  private initializeRoutes() {
    this.router.get(this.path, this.getAllPosts);
    this.router.get(`${this.path}/:id`, this.getPostById);
    this.router
      .all(`${this.path}/*`, authMiddleware)
      .patch(`${this.path}/:id`, validationMiddleware(CreatePostDto, true), this.modifyPost)
      .delete(`${this.path}/:id`, this.deletePost)
      .post(this.path, authMiddleware, validationMiddleware(CreatePostDto), this.createPost);
  }

  private getAllPosts = async (request: express.Request, response: express.Response) => {
    const posts = await this.post.find();
    response.send(posts);
  }

  private getPostById = async (request: express.Request, response: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) => {
    const id = request.params.id;
    const post = await this.post.findById(id);
    if (post) {
      response.send(post);
    } else {
      next(new PostNotFoundException(id));
    }
  }

  private modifyPost = async (request: express.Request, response: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) => {
    const id = request.params.id;
    const postData: Post = request.body;
    const post = await this.post.findByIdAndUpdate(id, postData, { new: true });
    if (post) {
      response.send(post);
    } else {
      next(new PostNotFoundException(id));
    }
  }

  private createPost = async (request: RequestWithUser, response: express.Response) => {
    const postData: CreatePostDto = request.body;
    const createdPost = new this.post({
      ...postData,
      authorId: request.user._id,
    });
    const savedPost = await createdPost.save();
    response.send(savedPost);
  }

  private deletePost = async (request: express.Request, response: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) => {
    const id = request.params.id;
    const successResponse = await this.post.findByIdAndDelete(id);
    if (successResponse) {
      response.send(200);
    } else {
      next(new PostNotFoundException(id));
    }
  }
}

export default PostsController;
~~~
```

Comment: This is very common error which I fixed it. I have to do request.params.id rather than request.params._id .